# Does Flink consider Kafka offsets upon application restart/bugfix?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I ran into a code bug in my Kafka-Flink application where I needed to redeploy the whole Flink application. I know about checkpoints and savepoints, but since my application had to restart, it will lose all the flink's internal checkpoints, and I hadn't created any savepoints.

However, my `commit.offsets.on.checkpoint` flag is true, so even if my internal flink checkpoints are lost, the kafka broker would have the last committed offset.

So in this case, will my restarted flink application read from that kafka broker's offset, or will it restart from all the way back in the kafka queue, because it had lost all its internal checkpoints?

Comment: Should be easy to test, no? What behavior are you currently seeing when you are restarting? In general, checkpoints override Kafka consumer groups. At least, that's how Spark is implemented. Checkpoints should always be stored on external, shared storage, not "internal" / in memory / node-local filesystem. Also, wouldn't you want to reset the offsets, anyway, to fix a processing bug, in other words, reprocess the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Flink is restarting from a checkpoint or savepoint, then Flink will use the offsets in that snapshot. Otherwise it will use the starting position configured in the KafkaSource or FlinkKafkaConsumer. If you haven't explicitly configured a starting position, then the KafkaSource will start from the earliest offset, and I'm not sure what the default was for the FlinkKafkaConsumer.

If you want to restart from a checkpoint or savepoint while ignoring the saved offsets (in order to pick up the rest of the saved state), then change the UID on the Kafka source operator, configure a specific starting position, and set the `--allowNonRestoredState` flag (since there will be saved offsets associated with the old uid that can't be restored).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you so much !